# SPSS: Pearson's r not significant but confidence intervals do not include 0

Tags: confidence-interval, spss, p-value, bootstrap, pearson-r

I have calculated the value of Pearson's *r* between two variables in SPSS, two tailed. Sample size is 81. The *r* value is -.21. The *p* value is .06. When I compute the 95% confidence intervals using bootstrapping with 2000 samples and the Bias corrected accelerated (BCa) option checked, I get confidence intervals [-0.36, -0.04] (does not include 0), indicating that in fact the result is significant at *p* < .05.

How do I explain the discrepancy between the *p* value and the confidence intervals?

I calculated the confidence intervals again with "percentile" instead of BCa checked and the confidence intervals were [-.378, .009] (does include 0), which makes more sense to me.

How can I explain the apparent incongruence between the *p* value and confidence intervals I attained when using the BCa method?

A secondary issue is how I would report this (BCa) result in APA style.

Comment: The significance test for r is going to correspond to the confidence interval that's not bootstrapped (the one you would compute using formulas). It seems your question is more about the difference between bias-corrected and percentile bootstrapped confidence intervals.

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems I do have some misunderstanding of the two different methods.

This issue must crop up from time to time though, when calculating confidence intervals (using BCa) results in a CI that seems at odds with the p value. The general question is - how do I interpret it?

Comment: What do you get with much larger number of bootstrap samples, e.g. 20'000?

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I tried it with 20,000 bootstrap samples, and I get CIs: [-.373 -.024]. I actually tried it several more times at 20,000 samples, and the CIs bounce around a very small amount. However, they still do not encompass 0.

Comment: Doesn't it concern you that your initial bootstrapped confidence interval doesn't contain the observed value of r?

Comment: @rolando2 - Thanks, that was an error. I've updated the original question. The r value does lie between the upper and lower confidence intervals, as it should!